# how can I get last trade result?

Tags: mql4, forex

How can I get the last trade result in mql4 bot?
I mean the part of code, mine does not work.
This is code, how can I do it?

```
   int a = 0;
  
   while(a == 0){
       OrderSend(Symbol(),OP_BUY,0.01,price,5,0,(Ask+0.0002),0,0,0,Green);
       a = 1;
   }

   //if(OrderSelect(OrdersTotal()-1, SELECT_BY_POS)==true){
   //    Print("Profit for the order 10 " + OrderProfit());
   //}
   //else{
   //    Print("OrderSelect returned the error of " + GetLastError());
   //}
   
   OrderSelect(OrderTicket(), SELECT_BY_POS);
   Print("Profit for the order 10 " + OrderProfit());
   OrderModify(OrderTicket(),OrderOpenPrice(),(Ask-0.0001),0,0,0);
   if(OrderProfit()<0){
       OrderSend(Symbol(),OP_SELL,0.01,price,5,0,0,0,0,0,Green);
   }
   else{
       OrderSend(Symbol(),OP_BUY,0.01,price,5,0,0,0,0,0,Red);
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

To select last open or pending order from trading pool:

```
OrderSelect(OrdersTotal()-1, SELECT_BY_POS);
```

If you want to select last closed or canceled order:

```
OrderSelect(OrdersHistoryTotal()-1, SELECT_BY_POS, MODE_HISTORY);
```

You can get more information in the docs [OrderSelect()](https://docs.mql4.com/trading/orderselect)

Comment: Not sure about this. In `OrderSelect()` spec they wrote "Sorting of the resulting list of orders cannot be guaranteed"

Comment: The whole sentence from specs is:
`Consecutive selection of orders using the SELECT_BY_POS parameter returns information in the sequence in which it was received from the trading server. Sorting of the resulting list of orders cannot be guaranteed.`

We don't use consecutive selection, so we don't expect list in that case, we expect only one result (we don't care about sorting). That is how i understand that.

Answer (score 0):

```
  double KapananPozisyon()
  {
   static datetime biletZaman=0;
   static double kar=0;
   for(int i=0; i<OrdersHistoryTotal(); i++)
     {
      if(OrderSelect(i,SELECT_BY_POS,MODE_HISTORY))
         if(biletZaman<OrderCloseTime())
           {
            kar=OrderProfit();
            biletZaman=OrderCloseTime();
           }
     }
   return kar;
  }
```